# Signification de « la régularisation »

Tags: vocabulaire, administration

J’ai reçu ce message de ma banque en France. J’y ai passé seulement quelque mois, donc mon vocabulaire n’est pas très fort. Le message :

> Je me permets de vous contacter concernant votre compte courant ouvert 
>   à la [banque] qui présent depuis 93 jours un solde débiteur de 14.71 € . 
>   Merci de bien vouloir à la régularisation dans les plus brefs délais.

Je comprends presque tout, mais qu’est que « la régularisation » veut dire ? Qu’est que la banque veut que je fasse ?
Merci bien…

Comment: La phrase en question n'est pas correcte, on dirait qu'il manque un mot. L'intention était surement d'écrire « procéder à la régularisation ».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ils veulent que vous payiez les 14.71 €.

« Régulariser » a le sens de « rectify » ou « resolve » en anglais.  La 9<sup>e</sup> édition du Dictionnaire de l'Académie française a la définition suivante :

*1. Rendre conforme à la loi ou à la règle en vigueur ce qui n’a pas été fait dans les conditions prévues. Régulariser une dépense, un compte financier.*

So, they are asking to you resolve the outstanding balance on your account.

Comment: @Amphiteóth Malheureusement, ce n'est pas possible de créer un lien vers le site web de la 9éme édition du Dictionnaire de l'Académie française.

Answer (score 0):

On peut faire appel à des notions de base en comptabilité pour comprendre. Le [*solde débiteur*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17029468) est une:

> [e]xpression indiquant que le total des sommes inscrites au débit du
>   compte est supérieur à celui des sommes figurant au crédit.

Il s'agit d'un solde dû. La [régularisation](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9gularisation) (aussi [ici](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8382079)) implique de remédier à la situation, tel qu'on [l'explique](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13324/3177), par l'ajout de fonds.